# Scikit-learn SVR Speed

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to build a kernel model for some training data. The model used is Support Vector Regression and the input data-set is about 58 samples with X a vector of size 5 and Y a double value. Example: X = [300678, 10,6,1,3] - Y = [18.38]. The training(fit) for this small data set is taking too long(over 5 minutes) is that reasonable or something goes wrong?

Comment: That doesn't sound right... Please post some code so we can see the SVMs parameters and initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data. Look at first feature of X, it is 300k. Another features are relatively smaller than the first feature. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html